# websphere Search REST API specification response format

Tags: java, websphere-8

I use below rest api and is work great.

Q: I want to remove some node, example: below node,

```
<atom:author>
```

how can I achieve this feature? thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <atom:feed xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
           xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           xmlns:wplc="http://www.ibm.com/wplc/atom/1.0"
           xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
           <atom:title>Search results for query "development" on scope "com.ibm.lotus.search.ALL_SOURCES"</atom:title>
           <atom:link href="searchfeed:search" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
           <atom:author>
               <atom:name>Enterprise Search API Web Service.</atom:name>
           </atom:author>
           <atom:id>searchfeed:search</atom:id>
           <atom:category term="com.ibm.lotus.search.ALL_SOURCES" label="com.ibm.lotus.search.ALL_SOURCES"/>
           <atom:updated>2013-01-14T08:35:27.482Z</atom:updated>
           <opensearch:totalResults exact="true">412</opensearch:totalResults>
           <opensearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="development"/>
           <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
           <opensearch:itemsPerPage>10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Remove from where?

Comment: I call this api via ajax for  my search  feature in my website, but some secure issue , I have to remove this node from response code. I want to re defined response format ,is this can achieive, or any other can deal with this problem thank you.